# using pointers in managed C++ in non-managed library methods

Tags: c++, .net, c, managed-c++

I have a managed C++ wrapper class for a non-managed C library. I came across an issue where it seems that the pointer I am sending from my managed C++ class is not pointing to the same memory location which is used by the non-managed C code library method.

```
MyNonManagedType* dataPointer;
getDataFromNonmanagedCLibrary(dataPointer);
// this gives me junk data, where field should be a char array
String^ myFieldValue = gcnew String(dataPointer->field);
```

Is it possible that the dataPointer is not pointing to the same address used by  the C library? Or maybe there is some kind of marshal method I need to use for this, or other pitfalls I may be missing?

Comment: The pointer `dataPointer` is uninitialized.  What can `getDataFromNonmanagedCLibrary` do with it, except to check if it's NULL?  It certainly cannot initialize it, since it is passed by value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: --http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705042/c-program-crashes-when-method-return-value-is-assigned-to-an-int

Answer (score 1):

If the pointer is not managed, given the code you have shown, there is no way for a `C` function to do anything with the uninitialized pointer except either:

1. Check it for NULL, and if so, do nothing with it, or
2. Use the address passed, and disaster happens.

You are passing the pointer by value, and passing by value means that the function will be using a local copy of the parameter that is passed, thus you see no changes when the function returns.  The function cannot set the pointer and have those changes reflect back to the caller the way it stands now.

Since we're talking about a `C` interface, you should change the `C` interface to this:

```
void getDataFromNonmanagedCLibrary(MyNonManagedType**);
```

A pointer to the pointer is passed.  Since we want to change the value passed to the function and have it reflect back to the caller, a pointer to the value is passed.  Since the value just happens to be a pointer, we pass a pointer to the pointer.

Then you rewrite `getDataFromNonmanagedCLibrary` to initialize the pointer by dereferencing it:

```
void getDataFromNonmanagedCLibrary(MyNonManagedType** ptr)
{
   *ptr = <the_address_you_expected_on_return>;
}
```

Then on the client side:

```
MyNonManagedType* dataPointer;
getDataFromNonmanagedCLibrary(&dataPointer);
```

Note that the address of the pointer is passed, no different than if you wanted to have a function change a non-pointer variable by passing the variable's address.